# why different effect in differnt browser after "onclick"

Tags: javascript, php

I want to enable the btn1 and disable btn2 on page-load. When I input value in txtbox1, then, on clicking btn1 ,btn1 should be disabled and enable btn2. If I click btn2, then btn2 should also be disabled.

```
$value= $_POST['tb1'.$id];
echo '<form name="f1" method="POST" action="">';
echo '<input type="text" id="txtbox1'.$id.'" name="tb1'.$id.'" value="'.$value.'" />';
echo '<input type="submit" id="btn1'.$id.'" name = "btnstart'.$id.'" value="START" onClick="document.getElementById(\'btn2'.$id.'\').disabled=false;this.disabled=true;"/><input type="submit" id="btn2'.$id.'" name = "btnend'.$id.'" value="End" onClick="this.disabled=true;" disabled/>';
echo '</form>';

if ( isset( $_POST['tb1'.$id] ) ) {
echo $value;
}
```

When I use Chrome, i can do the above button effects , but I cannot get the txtbox1 value.
When I use IE and Firefox, I can get the txtbox1 value, but the button effect is not want I want. Which means, I input value in txtbox1 then click btn1 only, then it will automatically enable btn2, then disable both then, then get back to the original status(btn1 enable, btn2 disable).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You have a typo in your code, line 5.

Comment: Fixed the typo mistake Thankyou

Comment: `echo 'testing value";` - your quotes don't match.

Comment: its just echo some text.

Comment: @TiesonT. I changed to echo the $value

Comment: @user3118482 : jquery an option????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have dynamic button names, its better not to touch them for disbale/enable feature that you want :

**Using jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 /*Operations on the 1st button click */
    $('#form').children("input[type='submit']:first").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); /*disable the 1st button */
        $('#form').children("input[type='submit']").eq(1).removeAttr("disabled"); /*enable the 2nd button */
    });

 /*Operations on the 2nd button click */
   $('#form').children("input[type='submit']").eq(1).click(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

    });
});
```

**Additionally :** give your form an id, something like :

```
echo '<form name="f1" id="form" method="POST" action="">';
 /* check the form id tag ^^ here*/
```

[**basic demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/QDrKj/)
but you wont be able to see full feature in it!!

Comment: so i dont need to have the onclick anymore? just `<input type="submit" id="btn1'.$vid.'" name = "btnstart'.$vid.'" value="START">` ?

Comment: @user3118482 : also, make sure to add jquery file on top of your code in `head` of your html

Comment: @user3118482 : if you dont understand any part...m still here, you can ask!! :D

Comment: two buttons are still enable on page-load

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45342/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-user3118482)

Comment: @user3118482 : please come on chat in above link!! :p

Answer (score 0):

never write your code like this, this makes debugging like pain, just make a `script` tag and handle everything there like this, the point here is about `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute`:

```
<?php
// your server side code
// finish declaring your variables like
$input_id = 'an_id';
$input_value = 'some_value';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>testing</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="f1" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="txtbox1<?php echo $input_id; ?>" name="tb1<?php echo $input_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $input_value; ?>" />
            <input type="button" id="btn1<?php echo $input_id; ?>" name="btnstart<?php echo $input_id; ?>" value="START" />
            <input type="button" id="btn2<?php echo $input_id; ?>" name="btnend<?php echo $input_id; ?>" value="End" disabled="disabled"/>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1<?php echo $input_id; ?>');
            btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2<?php echo $input_id; ?>');
            btn1.onclick = function() {
                console.log(this);
                btn1.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
                btn2.removeAttribute("disabled");
                return false;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```